# ¿Cómo mostrar mas texto on hover?

Tags: css, html5

En html,
necesito hacer un div que muestre una linea de texto
pero al sobrevolar con el ratón quiero que muestre otras líneas de texto
en mi ejemplo las que estan en el div "mensaje"
aunque tampoco se si esto se hace con div
gracias anticipadas!

```css
.linea{
   background-color: yellowgreen;
    width: 100%;
    color: #2c2b2b;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="linea">
    <p>linea 1</p>
</div>

<div class="mensaje">
    <p>linea 1</p>
    <p>linea 2</p>
    <p>linea 3</p>
    <p>linea 4</p>
    <p>linea 5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartirnos lo que ya intentaste?

Comment: ya lo he puesto, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr esto puedes usar `:hover` en CSS la cual aplica un estilo cuando pasas el mouse sobre dicho elemento, para lograr lo que buscas, ocultamos todos los elementos con la clase `oculta` y usando el selector `.mensaje:hover .oculta` modificamos la vista de todos los elementos.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```css
.mensaje {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 100%;
  color: #2c2b2b;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding: 1%;
}

.oculta {
  display: none;
}

.mensaje:hover .oculta {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mensaje">
    <p>linea 1</p>
    <p class="oculta">linea 2</p>
    <p class="oculta">linea 3</p>
    <p class="oculta">linea 4</p>
    <p class="oculta">linea 5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias, funciona perfectamente!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr que deseas tienes que usar `:hover` en `.linea`, pero para que se pueda mostrar el contenedor con la clase `.mensaje` este tiene que estar dentro del contenedor `.linea`.

Utiliza el siguiente código:

```css
.linea{
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 100%;
  color: #2c2b2b;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding: 1%;
}
.mensaje {
  display: none;
 }
 .linea:hover .mensaje {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="linea">
  <p>linea 1</p>
  <div class="mensaje">
      <p>linea 2</p>
      <p>linea 3</p>
      <p>linea 4</p>
      <p>linea 5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```